# Webgl loading json model issue

Tags: javascript, json, webgl

Ok... I have a model and when I write the vertices and indices directly in the javascript everything loads fine; however, if I try to load the very same model from a json call, the model says that it loaded but it never shows up.

Any ideas???

Here's the code: http://www.guioui.com/justforfun/webgl/index.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you made a small copy-paste error:

Your line 192

```
gl.bufferData(gl.ELEMENTS_ARRAY_BUFFER, new Uint16Array(model.normals), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
```

Should be

```
gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(model.normals), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
```

since it is an array buffer of floats - not a element array buffer.

Comment: Good catch, sometimes it helps to get a second pair of eyes on the code. Unfortunately though when I made that change it still isn't working. Going to recheck everything again now, if you don't mind taking another look at it in the mean time I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: You have not updated the example at  http://www.guioui.com/justforfun/webgl/index.htm

Comment: haha... oo man... forget it, it's working. I had been looking at the online version and making edits to the local. Some mornings... I tell ya. Thanks a lot Mortennobel!